# Failed to import Type Script to Java Script (Loading module from path was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”))

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I created a script in TS and I imported it to JS, but I got this error:
Loading module from the path) was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html").

I don't have any idea how I can fix it, I'm a beginner in JS and TS, well any help will be appreciated!

I'm using Firefox 77.0.1

I'm importing script in js using this code:

```
import { Script } from './path';
```

Thanks!